# asp.net C# Connection Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

hi guys i'm trying to create a connection class that can be used through out the entire project by just calling the object.

how can i add command parameter and how can i create a method for datareader?
this is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for AccessDb
/// </summary>
public class AccessDb
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    public DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public AccessDb()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    }

    public DataTable execDataTable(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dataTable);
            da.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('something wrong with the connection '"+ ex.Message +")</script>");
        }
        finally 
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

}
```

this is how i call the class method

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            AccessDb dbcon = new AccessDb();
            DataTable dt = dbcon.execDataTable("SELECT * FROM AGESNews");

            if (dbcon.dataTable.Rows.Count > 0) {
                grd.DataSource = dt;
                grd.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, where's the problem? The code doesn't work or doesn't compile or what?

Comment: @Lucero he want to provide CommandParameters to his DAL, but he can't do it because he gives only the string query.

Comment: Please review [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements) about how to dispose connections and about reusing connections (specifically why not to). You also need to adhere to Single Responsibility Principle, your db wrapper should not be writing to the response stream. It should either rethrow the exception wrapped in its own exception OR do not catch the exception at all.

Comment: Also there are plenty of ORMs out there that already do this type of thing, everything from the very configurable NHibernate or Entity Framework to those more simple like Massive and Subsonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your `ExecDataTable` take an `OleDbCommand`

```
public DataTable ExecDataTable(OleDbCommand cmd)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        if(cmd.Connection == null)
           cmd.Connection = con;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        da.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

So how you will invoke this method.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM AGESNews WHERE ID=@ID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", yourParameterIDValue);

DataTable dt = dbcon.execDataTable(cmd);
```

Comment: hi mybirthname!
your code is working thanks a lot :)

i have a favor can you create me a method for datareader?

Comment: @codenijuan you are welcome you can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: i have a little favor can you create me a method for datareader?

Comment: @codenijuan first try it for yourself if you have a problem you can ask new question. Look into the comments of Igor he mentioned to not share one connection this is bad practice. The policy here is one question per post.

Comment: ok i will try to code it in my own first.. thanks for your time :)